# which one is the best way to display HTML in Flex?

Tags: html, apache-flex, flex3

I want to use an external HTML file that I can import into my Flex App at run time.

I've heard of too many issues with the iFrame option, so I want to avoid that, if possible.

Does anyone have any other good suggestions for dealing with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

[Deng](http://deng.com.br/) might do the trick, but sadly it seems its development has been stopped since 2006 =/

There are a lot of others libraries to do this, but they all seem to use iframes.

EDIT:
You can also try this :
http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/
Seems interesting.

Comment: there is no samples are there.

Comment: Documentation and samples for Flash & Flex are available in the svn repository ( http://code.google.com/p/htmlwrapper/source/browse/#svn/trunk/versions/version1/examples )